# nilpotent ideal of incidence algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(I;\preceq)$ be a finite poset, where $I=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ and $\preceq$ is a partial order on $I$. The subset

$$KI=\{\lambda=[\lambda_{ij}]\in\mathbb{M}_n(K)\mid\lambda_{st}=0\text{ if } a_s\npreceq a_t\}$$

is called the *incidence algebra*. The radical of $KI$ is the set

$$U=\{\lambda=[\lambda_{ij}]\in KI\mid\lambda_{ii}=0, i=1,\ldots,n\}.$$

How I can prove that $U^n=0$?

Comment: This is discussed a bit in Examples 1.1 and 1.5 of _Elements of the Represenation Theory of Associative Algebras_ by Assem, Simson, and Skowronski.

Comment: Yes, I try to prove that $U$ is nilpotent ideal in example 1.5 b. This is not prove there.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you're reading that exact book. In that case, you know $U$ consists of strictly lower triangular matrices, and Matt Samuel's answer is the key. Maybe to convince yourself, try multiplying out arbitrary strictly lower triangular $3\times 3$ matrices, and see how the positions of the nonzero entries changes with each multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a linear extension of the partially ordered set to get an ordered basis for your vector space, and an operator in $U$ is then a strictly upper triangular matrix. Phrased this way it may perhaps seem easier to prove: the product of any $n$ strictly upper triangular matrices on an $n$ dimensional vector space is zero.

If you really get stuck I'll expand on this answer, but I don't want to deny you the pleasure of pushing indices around to prove this.